# Mysql query - how to do this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql and I want to calculate the sum of column ss.

If (id and ss) repeats it will take only one.

See image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szmSr.png)

thank you

Comment: have a look at [SQL DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) and [SQL SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
SELECT id,
       SUM( DISTINCT ss ) AS "Sum (ss)"
FROM tblData
GROUP BY id;
```

Note : Without `GROUP BY` `SUM()` will try to add up all values of `ss`, even with the `DISTINCT` qualifier.  If you use `GROUP BY` but not `DISTINCT` then `SUM()` will add up all the values of `ss` for a particular value of `id`, even if they are repeated.  Using `DISTINCT` in conjunction with `GROUP BY` here removes any repeated combinations before `SUM()` goes to work.